# "Global name is not defined" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning OOP and am struggling with it. The issue is probably staring me right in the face.

```
def Travel():
    choice = str()   
    choice = input("Where will you search?\nChoose F for Front or T for Trunk\n")
    if choice == "F":
        LocF()
    elif choice == "T":
        LocT(i)

def LocF():
    print("Looking through the front of the car, you find a screwdriver.\nYou figure that might help a bit.")
    inv = ("screwdriver")
    return i

def LocT(i):
    if i[0] == "screwdriver":
        print("You use your screwdriver to pop the inside of the trunk door lock off.")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("You make it to class with seconds to spare.")
    else:
        print("You can't get to the trunk yet.")
        Travel()
```

Comment: You didn't define i...

Comment: in `LocF()`, you create a variable `inv` but try to return a nonexistent variable `i`. Change one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you call the `Travel()` function first.

If `Travel()` was called, you will now input a string with the value of 'F' or 'T'.

If the input is 'F', `LocF()` will be called, in `LocF()` you returned `i` but you didn't define it.

If the input is 'T', `LocT()` will be called, and since there's no `i` in `Travel()` scope, the interpreter will look for `i` outside. And there's no `i` outside too, so the error is understandable.

There're a couple of ways to fix your code, but since I don't know what you trying to do so I can't help further.

And your problem is about static and dynamic scoping, not OOP.